# Why can't an object in JavaScript be a prototype of itself?

Tags: javascript, object, overriding, prototype

Taken the given code below and comparing it with the code after it:

```
var protoShoe = {isShoe:true, isGenderSpecific: false}  
protoShoe = Object.create(protoShoe); 

protoShoe.isGenderSpecific= true;  protoShoe.gender = "mens";  

protoShoe = Object.create(protoShoe);  

protoShoe.isGenderSpecific= false;  protoShoe.gender = "na";  

console.log("Is protoShoe prototype of protoShoe:" + protoShoe.isPrototypeOf(protoShoe));
console.log(protoShoe);
```

VS

```
var protoShoe = {isShoe:true, isGenderSpecific: false}  
mensShoe = Object.create(protoShoe); 

mensShoe.isGenderSpecific= true;  mensShoe.gender = "mens";  

protoShoe = Object.create(mensShoe);  

protoShoe.isGenderSpecific= false;  protoShoe.gender = "na";  

console.log("Is mensShoe prototype of protoShoe:" + mensShoe.isPrototypeOf(protoShoe));
console.log(protoShoe);
```

The final object appears to be pretty similar in it's inherited properties, but in the 1st case where we simply keep reusing the `protoShoe` object, at the end it is not a prototype of itself, **why is this? Any problems it would cause if it was?**

I'm just trying to understand prototype inheritance better and this was just a silly experiment but I found the `isPrototypeOf` value of the first to be interesting.

Comment: Is this a Javascript related question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `protoShoe` variable you create is a reference to an object. When you `protoShoe = Object.create(protoShoe);` you create a new object and overwrite the reference. It is not the same object, even though it is called the same. The old `protoShoe` still exists, but now the only reference to it is in the prototype of the new `protoShoe`.

Essentially what you're reusing is the name of the variable, not the object.

It is not possible to create an object that is the prototype of itself. At least in any JS runtime I checked. Because of how property lookup works, it would create an infinite loop.

When you have an object, say, `protoShoe`, and want to lookup a property on it, say, `notAShoeProperty`, JS first checks the object itself for that property. If it doesn't find it, it looks up the prototype chain. If it doesn't find it on the prototype, it looks in the prototype's prototype, etc. So if you had an object being it's own prototype, trying to find an undefined variable would result in an infinite loop.

And the only way I know to actually try creating such a prototype chain is by doing `protoShoe.__proto__ = protoShoe`. V8 complains about a cyclic proto value and throws an error then.

Comment: Makes sense. _When you protoShoe = Object.create(protoShoe); you create a new object and overwrite the reference. It is not the same object, even though it is called the same. The old protoShoe still exists, but now the only reference to it is in the prototype of the new protoShoe._ makes this clear. Thank you for your help, I understood before hand that it was a silly thing to do, but I figured understanding the reason why this doesn't work would also cement a few other concepts in my brain. Hopefully others find this silly question, but well explained answer helpful!